# SSAS Tabular Refreshing only new data

Tags: ssis, ssas, sql-job

i have a tabular cube which takes a long time to processing, my idea is to process only new data every hour and a full process during the night,  is there a way to do that with SSIS and SQL Job?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Hi, i am using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your "new rows" are inserts to your fact table rather than updates or deletes you can do a ProcessAdd operation. ProcessAdd will take a SQL query you provide that returns the new rows and add them to your table in SSAS Tabular.

There are several ways to automate this, all of which could be run from SSIS. This [article](http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/incremental-processing-in-tabular-using-process-add/) walks through the options well.

If you have updates and deletes then you need to partition your table inside SSAS. For example partition by week then only reprocess (ProcessData) the partitions where any rows have been inserted/updated/deleted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice. The thing is that all changes in data have to be process, Deletes, Updates or Inserts, i already tested the ProcessAdd operation and only insert new data. Another advice?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps